# MinGW possibly linking to 64bit dlls

Tags: gcc, mingw, sfml

I'm trying to get [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) to work with Eclipse but I'm unsuccessfull(running MinGW 3.17-2 and gcc 4.8.1)

The file is compiled but when I try to run it I get the following error:
[image]

Looking in my `MinGW\bin` folder I can only see a `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` file and after some searching it appears that the dll asked for is for a 64-bit version? My OS is 64 bit but both MinGW and the SFML libraries all 32-bit.

How can I resolve this?

Makefile:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: Test

# Tool invocations
Test: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
    g++ -L"F:\Libs\SFML-2.2\lib" -o "Test" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(CC_DEPS)$(C++_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(OBJS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS) Test
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

objects.mk:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

USER_OBJS :=

LIBS := -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-system-d -lsfml-window-d
```

sources.mk:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

C_UPPER_SRCS := 
CXX_SRCS := 
C++_SRCS := 
OBJ_SRCS := 
CC_SRCS := 
ASM_SRCS := 
C_SRCS := 
CPP_SRCS := 
O_SRCS := 
S_UPPER_SRCS := 
CC_DEPS := 
C++_DEPS := 
EXECUTABLES := 
OBJS := 
C_UPPER_DEPS := 
CXX_DEPS := 
C_DEPS := 
CPP_DEPS := 

# Every subdirectory with source files must be described here
SUBDIRS := \
. \
```

subdir.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
CPP_SRCS += \
../main.cpp 

OBJS += \
./main.o 

CPP_DEPS += \
./main.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
%.o: ../%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler'
    g++ -I"F:\Libs\SFML-2.2\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

Comment: Which package did you download from the SFML website and where did you get your MinGW version from? You have to use the exact same compiler as the SFML binaries were built with.

Comment: @Lukas I've used GCC 4.8.1 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit package of SFML package and the setup from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/

Comment: Try adding `-static-libgcc` to the linker flags (maybe you want `-static-libstdc++` too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way name mangling and non-standardized ABI work in C++, there is unfortunately about no compatibility between different versions of compilers. In your case, you're even trying to use a library compiled with a compiler from a different "MinGW" project than your current compiler is. But even if you were using the same "type" of compiler, C++ libraries usually aren't reusable across minor or patch versions.

First of I really recommend to not use the original MinGW project and rather go for a compiler based on the [MinGW-w64 project](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/). If you want reasons for that, you can ask Google, there are enough discussion about it.

Second you either need to pick a compiler that matches on of the SFML packages OR you need to build SFML yourself.

- For the *GCC 4.9.2 MinGW (DW2) - 32-bit* package I used [this compiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-posix/dwarf/i686-4.9.2-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-rev0.7z/download).
- For the *GCC 4.7.1 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit* package I used the compiler that shipped with [this Code::Blocks package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe).
- For the *GCC 4.8.1 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit* package I used the compiler that shipped with [this Code::Blocks package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe).

And third, if you want the latest development version of SFML using the latest compiler versions, you can check out my [Nightly Builds](http://nightlybuilds.ch/project/show/1/SFML/).